# Multiple dummy monitors on remote headless Linux for VNC to local multiple monitors

Tags: display, xrandr, monitors, headless, x11vnc

I submit defeat. I have been trying to configure my remote Linux box to have two dummy monitors so that I can use multiple local monitors to VNC into it. I'm surprised that no one else has needed help with this to find something on the web.

I've also tried creating a monitor on the Linux box that is double wide. Then use x11vnc to -clip an area for each display. But I'm having issues creating a monitor that large with the dummy driver.

I do have a graphics adapter installed that has two DisplayPorts but am not planning to use it. When I was using the real adapter, I was getting sluggish behavior. When I tried the dummy, it was very responsive. So I'm hoping to just create another dummy.

I'm using KDE DM.

I have seen many examples of using VIRTUAL1 but I can't get that working with the dummy driver. I tried adding Option "VirtualHeads" "2" into the config but the dummy driver doesn't recognize it.

I’ve seen suggestions of using Xvfb but it has been deprecated by the dummy driver since 2016.

Here are some details.

```
$ uname -a
Linux bgrupczy-linux 5.8.0-53-generic #60~20.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Thu May 6 09:52:46 UTC 2021 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/xorg.conf is empty

The following was gleaned from searching the internet. Once I got it working I stopped tweaking it so it may have flaws but that don't seem to affect me.

/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/dummy-1920x1080.conf has the following which gets me my single 1920x1080.

```
Section "Monitor"
  Identifier "Monitor0"
  HorizSync 28.0-80.0
  VertRefresh 48.0-75.0
  Modeline "1920x1080_60.00" 173.00 1920 2048 2248 2576 1080 1083 1088 1120 -hsync +vsync
EndSection

Section "Device"
  Identifier "Card0"
  Driver "dummy"
  VideoRam 256000
EndSection

Section "Screen"
  Identifier "Screen0"
  Device "Card0"
  Monitor "Monitor0"
  DefaultDepth 24
  SubSection "Display"
    Depth 24
    Modes "1920x1080_60.00"
  EndSubSection
EndSection
```

```
$ xrandr
xrandr: Failed to get size of gamma for output default
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 240, current 1920 x 1080, maximum 1920 x 1080
default connected 1920x1080+0+0 0mm x 0mm
   1920x1080     60.00* 
   1680x1050     70.00    60.00  
   1400x1050     70.00    60.00  
   1600x900      60.00  
   1280x1024     75.00    60.00  
   1440x900      60.00  
   1400x900      60.00  
   1280x960      60.00  
   1368x768      60.00  
   1360x768      60.00  
   1280x800      60.00  
   1152x864      75.00    70.00    60.00  
   1280x720      60.00  
   1024x768      75.00    70.00    60.00  
   1024x576      60.00  
   960x600       60.00  
   832x624       75.00  
   960x540       60.00  
   800x600       75.00    72.00    60.00    56.00  
   840x525       70.00    60.00  
   864x486       60.00  
   700x525       70.00    60.00  
   800x450       60.00  
   640x512       75.00    60.00  
   720x450       60.00  
   700x450       60.00  
   640x480       75.00    73.00    60.00  
   684x384       60.00  
   680x384       60.00  
   640x400       60.00  
   576x432       75.00    70.00    60.00  
   640x360       60.00  
   512x384       75.00    70.00    60.00  
   512x288       60.00  
   416x312       75.00  
   480x270       60.00  
   400x300       75.00    72.00    60.00    56.00  
   432x243       60.00  
   320x240       75.00    73.00    60.00
```

```
$ lspci | grep VGA
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Device 9bc5 (rev 05)
```

I can see from xrandr that my monitor is called "default". So I tried this:

```
$ cvt 3840 1080
# 3840x1080 59.96 Hz (CVT) hsync: 67.16 kHz; pclk: 346.00 MHz
Modeline "3840x1080_60.00"  346.00  3840 4088 4496 5152  1080 1083 1093 1120 -hsync +vsync
```

```
$ xrandr --newmode "3840x1080_60.00"  346.00  3840 4088 4496 5152  1080 1083 1093 1120 -hsync +vsync
$ xrandr --addmode default "3840x1080_60.00"
$ xrandr --output default --mode "3840x1080_60.00"
```

The last line gives me:

```
xrandr: Configure crtc 0 failed
```

I tried to increase VideoRam to 512000 (double) to make sure I had room. Not sure what to do there. I have 32G ram.

And ALL xrandr commands give me:
`xrandr: Failed to get size of gamma for output default`
and I figure that's because it's a dummy monitor that has no gamma.

I'm currently Working within the VNC session. Do I need to shut down x11vnc to get xrandx to complete? I'm at my wits end.

I'm starting x11vnc like this:

```
x11vnc -loop -forever -shared -repeat -noxdamage -xrandr -display :0 -clip 1920x1080+0+0
```

The linux box is within my local net so I'm not concerned with authentication/passwords.

**Edit 2021-05-27:**

More lurking and I found some options. I was able to get a double wide screen and then create two x11vnc instances. But this isn't optimal. The Linux box still sees this as a single screen. Now is there a way to take that screen and tell the Linux box to split it? For example, if I maximize a window in KDE it will not span both local screens?

Xorg conf file:

```
Section "Monitor"
  Identifier "Monitor0"
EndSection

Section "Device"
  Identifier "Card0"
  Driver "dummy"
  VideoRam 512000
EndSection

Section "Screen"
  Identifier "Screen0"
  Device "Card0"
  Monitor "Monitor0"
  DefaultDepth 24
  SubSection "Display"
    Depth 24
    Virtual 3840 1080
  EndSubSection
EndSection
```

```
x11vnc -loop -forever -shared -repeat -noxdamage -xrandr -display :0 -rfbport 5900 -clip 1920x1080+0+0
x11vnc -loop -forever -shared -repeat -noxdamage -xrandr -display :0 -rfbport 5901 -clip 1920x1080+1920+0
```

I can then connect to VNC displays :0 and :1 and arrange them on local monitors and resize the windows to fit those monitors.

When a dialog window appears, many times it's in the middle of the Linux "big screen" which for me spans both monitors...

**Edit 2021-11-12:**

One solution: https://superuser.com/a/1188573/514658

The real issue is not being able to get my VNC viewer to go full screen and only span two of my three monitors. The only option available  in the viewer is to use ALL monitors which then blocks my use of the Windows side. DisplayFusion at above link did the trick. Now I can seamlessly drag between my two monitors and not get stuck on the edge of one.

**Edit 2021-11-16:**

"SOLVED": Instead of using DisplayFusion, which is a big hammer, more searching led me to Windows PowerShell. No need for a third party utility. I only need to move/resize a specific window to fit on two of my three monitors full screen. Here it is:

```
Add-Type @"
  using System;
  using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

  public class Win32 {
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
    public static extern bool GetWindowRect(IntPtr hWnd, out RECT lpRect);

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
    public static extern bool GetClientRect(IntPtr hWnd, out RECT lpRect);

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
    public static extern bool MoveWindow(IntPtr hWnd, int X, int Y, int nWidth, int nHeight, bool bRepaint);
  }

  public struct RECT
  {
    public int Left;        // x position of upper-left corner
    public int Top;         // y position of upper-left corner
    public int Right;       // x position of lower-right corner
    public int Bottom;      // y position of lower-right corner
  }

"@

$h = (Get-Process vnc-E4_6_3-x86_win32_viewer).MainWindowHandle
[Win32]::MoveWindow($h, 1920, 0, 3840, 1080, $true )
```

Answer (score 0):

The following X config works for me on a headless workstation and enables dual dummy monitors using x11vnc + vncviewer.
It uses X dummy driver (dummy_drv.so).  I haven't tried setting up using Xvfb app which may work also. KDE has some bugs in moving windows around though.

```
# darwin
Section "Monitor"
    Identifier  "Monitor1"
    HorizSync   60.0-100.0
    VertRefresh 60-120
    Option "Primary" "True"
    Option "Enable" "True"
    Option "Position" "0 0"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
    Identifier  "Monitor2"
    HorizSync   60.0-100.0
    VertRefresh 60-120
    Option "Primary" "False"
    Option "Enable" "True"
    Option "Position" "1280 0"
    Option "RightOf" "Monitor1"
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier  "Device1"
    Driver      "dummy"
    VideoRam    512000
    # DUMMY0 and DUMMY1 are driver names guessed from
    # errors in /var/log/Xorg.0.log and also
    # checking xorg-server src pkg.
    Option "Monitor-DUMMY0" "Monitor1"
    Option "Monitor-DUMMY1" "Monitor2"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier  "Screen1"
    Device      "Device1"
    Monitor     "Monitor1"
    DefaultDepth 24
    SubSection "Display"
            Modes "1280x1024"
    EndSubSection   
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier  "Screen2"
    Device      "Device1"
    Monitor     "Monitor2"
    DefaultDepth 24
    SubSection "Display"
            Modes "1280x1024"
    EndSubSection   
EndSection

Section "ServerLayout"
    Identifier "Layout 1"
    Screen 0 "Screen1"
    Screen 1 "Screen2" RightOf "Screen1"
EndSection
                
Section "ServerFlags"
    Option "DefaultServerLayout" "Layout 1"
    # XRANDR extension is more recent and can replace older XINERAMA extension.
    # dummy_drv.so can easily be recompiled from latest source to support XRANDR.
    # If XRANDR is supported by dummy_drv.so, set the following to false.
    # Ubuntu 20.04 dummy_drv.so don't support XRANDR yet,
    # so the following must be set to true.
    Option "Xinerama"  "False"
EndSection
```

Comment: Thank you! I will try this on the new setup I’m planning. Old rig is gone so I can’t give immediate feedback.